# Deleting apigee permission on a role using the api

Tags: apigee

I have created a userrole and I am now unable to delete one of the permissions on it using the api.  I wanted to block all access to a resource so I created it with a empty array of http verbs. This is possible using both the [single](http://apigee.com/docs/management/apis/post/organizations/%7Borg_name%7D/userroles/%7Brole_name%7D/permissions) and [multi](http://apigee.com/docs/management/apis/post/organizations/%7Borg_name%7D/userroles/%7Brole_name%7D/resourcepermissions) add permission resources like so

```
POST /userroles/readonly/permissions" -d '{"path" : "/resource", "permissions" : []}' -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

However now that I want to delete that permission from the role I am unable to as the [delete](http://apigee.com/docs/management/apis/delete/organizations/%7Borg_name%7D/userroles/%7Brole_name%7D/permissions/%7Bpermission%7D) takes the http verb in the path and is mandatory, as there is no http verb in my case the call fails and I am unable to do a delete. If I had a verb then it would look like this

```
DELETE "/userroles/readonly/permissions/get?path=/resource"
```

If I call the api with no verb specified it fails with this error:

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
...
"code" : "security.QueryParamResourcePathCannotBeNull",
"message" : "Query parameter path cannot be null or empty",
"contexts" : [ ]
```

I dont really want to delete the role and recreate it if that can be avoided.

Any ideas? This seems like a bit of a design flaw in the permissions system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in your example above there is no permission to delete.

Why do not you try to add a 'get' permission at fiest by the same POST call and then DELETE if you like. POST works even if you have already modified a resource permission.

In that case the DELETE call results in a proper delete response.

Pls do comment how it goes.

Step1

```
curl http://hostname/v1/organizations/myorg/userroles/role1/permissions  -u "admin@org.com:***" -d '{"path" : "/resource", "permissions" : ["get"]}' -H "Content-Type:application/json" -v
```

Step2

```
curl -X DELETE  "http://hostname/v1/organizations/myorg/userroles/role1/permissions/get?path=/resource"  -u "admin@org.com:***"   -v
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried this out but I still end up with the permission I cant delete. The POST adds the get like you suggest but when I do the delete on the get I still end up with the /resource having a empty array of permissions.

Comment: Note that the first step here is to actually adding a permission with a valid verb.  Did that step go without error for you? If not what is the response you get when you add a valid permission?

Comment: Yep the post works correctly and I get back a 201 response with a body like `{
  "path" : "/resource",
  "permissions" : [ "get" ]
}`  If I do a GET request I see the permission with the valid verb but then when I do the delete (which returns a 200 response with the same body as above) the resourcePermission still exists and it just has no verb.

Comment: Oops.. Looks like the entry with "" or null is possibly created in the DB. Can't think of any quick-fix in that case.